# Fragment not receiving menu callbacks

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment

I have a fragment class that extends `Fragment` and calls `setHasOptionsMenu` to participate in the menu. This class also implements `onCreateOptionsMenu`, `onPrepareOptionsMenu` and `onOptionsItemSelected`.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        ....
}
```

I'm dynamically loading this fragment using a `FragmentTransaction` in my Activity (that extends `FragmentActivity`).

However none of the menu callbacks (`onCreateOptionsMenu`, `onPrepareOptionsMenu` and `onOptionsItemSelected`) are being called (I've debugged with some breakpoints in those methods) and the menu isn't shown.

Am I missing something? Do I need to add something in my Activity?

I'm using the Android Compatibility Library, compiling with L11 SDK and testing in a Xoom.

**EDIT**: I've found the problem. My AndroidManifest is targeting L11, this seems to hide the menu button and prevent from the callbacks being called. However if I remove this from the manifest I loose some other features I need (for example the activated state in lists). Does anyone know how to solve this issue (enable the menu button) without removing the `targetSdkVersion=11` from the Manifest?

Comment: Can you confirm that your fragment is actually being loaded, i.e. in onCreate being called?

Comment: Yes I can confirm that. Also I've tried to load it statically, meaning to define the fragment in the activity layout, still no menu.

Comment: @aromero Nothing obvious springs to mind. You can implement these methods in your fragment class. I'm assuming that onCreateView is returning an inflated view so that your fragment does have a UI? If not then the menu won't be shown. If so then I would suggest debugging the compatibility library sources to see why the messages aren't being dispatched.

Comment: @PJL thanks will try debugging the library. The fragment does have an UI and everything else is working fine.

Comment: I've found the problem. I'll edit my question.

Comment: @aromero I have the following which works a treat for me `<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="4" android:targetSdkVersion="11"/>`

Comment: @PJL Are you compiling using SDK 11? Are you testing using a Xoom? In my case only removing the targetSdkVersion=11 makes the difference

Comment: @aromero OK using 3.0 SDK (10) using the CPL and testing using a Xoom. Maybe the difference is the SDK.

Comment: @PJL Thanks, BTW API 10 is Android 2.3.3, not 3.0

Comment: @aromero sorry yes 11, must of been thinkign about r10 tools.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found the problem. The AndroidManifest is targeting SDK 11, this seems to hide the menu button and prevent from the callbacks being called. I assume that this breaks the compatibility of the menu button that seems to be replaced by the action bar in Android 3.0

Comment: @aromro As mentioned above I'm targeting SDK 11 without problem. What is your min SDK version set to?

Comment: @PJL minSdkVersion is 8 (because I'm using C2DM).

Answer (score 29):

Aromero,
Don't forget to override the onCreateOptionsMenu using the fragment version of the method, similar to this:

```
    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu (Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.queue_options, menu);
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    }
```

This goes in the fragment, by the way, and adds to the inflated menu of the Activity, if there is one. Had the same problem myself, until I figured this out.

Kim

Comment: You also need to make sure you call setHasOptionsMenu(true); in your onCreate or onCreateView

Comment: This is not working inside nested fragment inside a fragment with viewpager!

Answer (score 9):

If you're having this problem with ActionBarSherlock, you need to make sure your Fragments are SherlockFragments, not mere SupportFragments, and that what you're overriding is

```
public void onPrepareOptionsMenu (com.actionbarsherlock.view.Menu menu) {
```

NOT

```
public void onPrepareOptionsMenu (android.view.Menu menu) {
```

If you do the latter, you should get some sort of warning about the function being final and you being unable to override it.  This is a warning that you're trying to override the wrong function!

If you fix the error by switching the class from SherlockFragment to a mere Fragment, you can create the function . . . but it won't get called.

Comment: This solved it for me, after a long time googling for this problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 9):

I had the same problem, but i think its better to summarize and introduce the last step to get it working:

1. Add setHasOptionsMenu(true) method in your Fragment's `onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)` method.
2. Override `onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater)` (if you want to do something different in your Fragment's menu) and `onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)` methods in your Fragment.
3. Inside your `onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)` Activity's method, make sure you return false when the menu item action would be implemented in `onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)` Fragment's method.

An example:

***Activity***

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getSupportMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.activity_menu_item:
        // Do Activity menu item stuff here
        return true;
    case R.id.fragment_menu_item:
        // Not implemented here
        return false;
    default:
        break;
    }

    return false;
}
```

***Fragment***

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    ....
}

@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Do something that differs the Activity's menu here
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.activity_menu_item:
        // Not implemented here
        return false;
    case R.id.fragment_menu_item:
        // Do Fragment menu item stuff here
        return true;
    default:
        break;
    }

    return false;
}
```

I hope this will be helpful.

Cheers.

Answer (score 6):

If you have an activity and a fragment that each loads menu items then you need to take special care of which overrides you use.

Activities can override **onOptionsItemSelected** and **onMenuItemSelected**, however fragments can only override **onOptionsItemSelected**.

If you override **onMenuItemSelected** in your activity and **onOptionsItemSelected** in your fragment, your fragment override will never get triggered.

Instead, use **onOptionsItemSelected** in both activity and fragment.

Comment: man. thank you. this was the case for me... i don't think I would have  ever noticed the 2 different hooks...

Answer (score 5):

You need to make sure you call `setHasOptionsMenu(true);` `onCreate` or `onCreateView` is called in your fragment.

You also need to implement the override of `onCreateOptionsMenu` inside your fragment.

Answer (score 4):

Another possible case is when you use a common id for a common action in each fragment; for instance R.id.action_add

Today I had such situation: hitting the option menu [add] was invoked the "wrong" `onOptionItemSelected` because each fragment (replaced dynamically using a `DrawerLayout`) had the same `R.id.action_add`.

Short story, if you have such situation always check that your fragment is visible:

`if (!isVisible()) return false;`

Long story, pay attention at the `onOptionItemSelected` chain!

```
  MainActivity
       |
       |  onOptionItemSelected
       +-----------------------
       |     return false
       |
 MyCoolFragment1
       |
       |  onOptionItemSelected
       +-----------------------
       |     return false
       |
 MyCoolFragment2
       |
       |  onOptionItemSelected
       +-----------------------
       |     return true
       |
[item selection handled]
```

If you add your fragments with (something like) this:

```
getSupportFragmentManager()
   .beginTransaction()
   .replace(R.id.content_frame, MyCoolFragment1.newInstance())
   .commit()
```

and you have defined the same id for a common action (let's say R.id.action_add) in each fragment;
don't forget to add this line to each:  if (!isVisible()) return false;

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (!isVisible()) return false; // <-- Not visible? skip!

    if (item.getItemId() == R.id.action_add) {
        //.TODO whatever
        return true;  //.Handled!
    }

    return false; //.Skip
}
```

Comment: dude thanx. was returning true in onOptionItemSelected in the activity , it was not reaching the fragments onOptionItemSelected.

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem when I was using the ViewPagerIndicator in conjunction with ActionBarSherlock.  Although it appeared this was [fixed](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/actionbarsherlock/oi_8OI3ytZI) I still ran into the problem.  The work around I found was to call into the fragment manually.

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
{
    Toast.makeText(this, "From activity", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); // TODO
    Fragment currentFragment = mAdapter.getItem(mPager.getCurrentItem());
    if (currentFragment != null && currentFragment instanceof SherlockFragment)
    {
        ((SherlockFragment)currentFragment).onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

}
```

Comment: i have the same problem in sherlock fragments. where you put this function? in activity or in fragment?

Comment: I originally had this code inside the activity, calling the fragment, but this actually isn't necessary. In the fragment's onCreateView or onCreate method just call setHasOptionsMenu(true);  Then when you override onOptionsItemSelected and onCreateOptionsMenu they get called correctly.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have implemented `onCreateOptionsMenu`, `onPrepareOptionsMenu` and `onOptionsItemSelected` in the class that `extends Fragment`. Try by doing that in your Activity class where you are loading this fragment

Comment: Yes those methods are implemented in the Fragment class. The Activity is a "multi pane" activity, meaning that the menu should only be shown when that specific fragment is showed. This example implements onCreateOptionsMenu in the Fragment class http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/FragmentMenu.html

Comment: You can quite happily put the menu methods in the class that extends Fragment.

Comment: Yes PJL, You are right we can put this methods there. But once i tried in fragment class it didn't worked for me and when i changed to Main activity it worked. May be i have done something wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem and solution that worked for me is:

1. Remove or comment any `onOptionsItemSelected()` ,`onMenuItemSelected()` even `onPrepareOptionMenu()` and leave in Activity `onCreateOptionsMenu()` only:

   ```
   @Override
   public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
   MenuInflater inflater=getMenuInflater();
   inflater.inflate(R.layout.menu, menu);
   return true;
   }
   ```
2. In Fragment class, in onCreateView(), put:

   ```
   setHasOptionsMenu(true);
   ```
3. In Fragment class add :

   ```
   @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu,inflater);      
    }

   @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){           
            switch(item.getItemId()){
            case R.id.action_insert:
               //doing stuff
            return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
   ```

Tested and worked on Android 4.4

Answer (score 1):

From the android developer site - [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html)

> Note: If you inflate menu items from a fragment, via the Fragment
>   class's onCreateOptionsMenu() callback, the system calls
>   onOptionsItemSelected() for that fragment when the user selects one of
>   those items. However, the activity gets a chance to handle the event
>   first, so ***the system first calls onOptionsItemSelected() on the
>   activity, before calling the same callback for the fragment***. To ensure
>   that any fragments in the activity also have a chance to handle the
>   callback, always pass the call to the superclass as the default
>   behavior instead of returning ***false*** when you do not handle the item.

Therefore [Marco HC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2659558/marco-hc) is the best answer of all.

Comment: If the activity has a switch handling the same item as the fragment, the activity one will be called.

Answer (score 1):

If your toolbar is defined in the parent activity xml, make sure you do this in your fragment

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ....
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
}
```

And then of course, override onCreateOptionsMenu like below

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.edit_menu, menu);
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}
```

This is the only solution that worked for me!