# How to add Options Menu to Fragment in Android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-optionsmenu

I am trying to add an item to the options menu from a group of fragments.

I have created a new `MenuFragment` class and extended this for the fragments I wish to include the menu item in. Here is the code:

Java:

```
public class MenuFragment extends Fragment {

    MenuItem fav;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    }

    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        fav = menu.add("add");
        fav.setIcon(R.drawable.btn_star_big_off);
    }
}
```

Kotlin:

```
class MenuFragment : Fragment {

    lateinit var fav: MenuItem

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setHasOptionsMenu(true)
    }

    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu, inflater: MenuInflater) {
        fav = menu.add("add");
        fav.setIcon(R.drawable.btn_star_big_off);
    }
}
```

For some reason the `onCreateOptionsMenu` appears not to run.

Comment: maybe a silly question... you press the menu button right?

Comment: ..lol...yes I have pressed the menu button, I have also tried it with and without: fav.setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS);

Comment: Hi, maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6324275/703919) thread will help you or check the [api demo](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/FragmentMenu.html) for a working example.

Comment: https://droidmentor.com/how-to-use-fragment-specific-menu-in-android/

Comment: There is a new of doing this since androidx.activity:activity:1.4.0. See my new answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73080607/8133841

Answer (score 682, accepted):

Call the super method:

Java:

```java
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        // TODO Add your menu entries here
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    }
```

Kotlin:

```kotlin
    override fun void onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setHasOptionsMenu(true)
    }

    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu, inflater: MenuInflater) {
        // TODO Add your menu entries here
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater)
    }
```

Put log statements in the code to see if the method is not being called or if the menu is not being amended by your code.

Also ensure you are calling `setHasOptionsMenu(boolean)` in `onCreate(Bundle)` to notify the fragment that it should participate in options menu handling.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I added the super method, and realised I had removed the @Override so added this back in, eclipse threw an error so I replaced the MenuInflater to import android.view.MenuInflater; instead of import android.support.v4.view.MenuInflater; and now all is working

Comment: not calling setHasOptionsMenu(true) in the Fragment's onCreate has gotten me twice now

Comment: I was transferring my Activity to a Fragment and ran into this issue. The method signature has changed from public boolean to public void and the arguments have also changed. Make sure to take note of this!

Comment: Note that Fragment.onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu, MenuInflater) is an empty method, so calling super is not required at all. The only mistake here was the wrong method signature and possibly a missing setHasOptionsMenu() in onCreate()

Comment: That may be so but it is still worth mentioning for the people using Activities instead of Fragments and by the upvotes, many people agree and were helped by this answer.

Comment: You know, in Java a method is identified, in part, with a name (as you used), and a CLASS. So, please, when you suggest to override a method, please, please give the class. Especially as there are two objects that may be manipulated (`Fragment`and `Activity`, and the `Fragment` usually has its `onCreateView()` method overridden while the `Activity` has its `onCreate()` method overridden).

Comment: The question already stated that the Class was Fragment as part of its text and in the code sample. There was no need to repeat it.

Comment: is it possible to first remove all existing items from the menu then add an item.

Comment: @Saifee please open your own question as what you asked is not relevant to this one.

Comment: I'm using a `Toolbar` and had to call `setHasOptionsMenu(true)` in `onCreateView()` instead `onCreate()` to get it done.

Comment: Replace super.onCreateOptionsMenu with inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_custom, menu);

Comment: There is a new of doing this since `androidx.activity:activity:1.4.0`. See my new answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73080607/8133841

Comment: onCreateOptionMenu is deprected. how can we acheive this with addMenuProvider ?

Answer (score 219):

I had the same problem, but I think it's better to summarize and introduce the last step to get it working:

1. Add setHasOptionsMenu(true) method in your Fragment's `onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)` method.
2. Override `onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater)` (if you want to do something different in your Fragment's menu) and `onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)` methods in your Fragment.
3. Inside your `onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)` Activity's method, make sure you return false when the menu item action would be implemented in `onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)` Fragment's method.

An example:

***Activity***

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getSupportMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {

        case R.id.activity_menu_item:

            // Do Activity menu item stuff here
            return true;

        case R.id.fragment_menu_item:

            // Not implemented here
            return false;
        default:
            break;
    }

    return false;
}
```

***Fragment***

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    ....
}

@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    // Do something that differs the Activity's menu here
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {

        case R.id.activity_menu_item:

            // Not implemented here
            return false;
        case R.id.fragment_menu_item:

            // Do Fragment menu item stuff here
            return true;

        default:
            break;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: On a viewPager on some devices the menu is only shown the second time the you go to the fragment

Comment: @Marco HC your code works fine. But what if i want to hide some of the menu for Activity or for Fragment? You have mention about where to implement which option menu (In activity and fragment). But what if i want to hide some menu?

Comment: @iDroidExplorer just keep a reference to that MenuItem and set visibility to gone or invisible. It's that your question?

Comment: @iDroidExplorer I tried his code and I don't know how but it automatically hide the menu when I switch to other fragments.

Comment: How to show Option Menu from Fragment with fragment's button click event?

Comment: keeps on forgetting to add this... setHasOptionsMenu(true);

Comment: Thank you for the callout in number 3 

Answer (score 162):

If you find the `onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater)` method is not being invoked, make sure you call the following from the Fragment's `onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)` method:

```
setHasOptionsMenu(true)
```

Comment: It gives me Error like NullPointerException

Comment: Good point. I was calling the setHasOptionMenu method from the static newInstance method. As I was only attaching my fragment when savedInstanceState was null, when the screen configuration changed the menu would not be created. The onCreate method of the fragment is the correct place where to set setHasOptionMenu to true.

Comment: I'm using a `Toolbar` and had to call `setHasOptionsMenu(true)` in `onCreateView()` instead `onCreate()` to get it done.

Comment: **'setHasOptionsMenu(Boolean): Unit' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java.** This method is no longer needed when using a MenuProvider to provide a Menu to your activity, which replaces onCreateOptionsMenu as the recommended way to provide a consistent, optionally Lifecycle-aware, and modular way to handle menu creation and item selection.

Answer (score 82):

If you need a `menu` to refresh a `webview` inside a specific `Fragment`, you can use:

**Fragment**:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
}

@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {

    // TODO Add your menu entries here
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.exit:
        System.exit(1);
        break;

    case R.id.refresh:
        webView.reload();
        break;
    }
    return true;

}
```

#### menu.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/exit" android:title="Exit" android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_cancel" />
    <item android:id="@+id/refresh" android:title="Refresh" android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_refresh" />
</menu>
```

Comment: This is a great answer, where I was looking for a way to merge app bar from activity and additional options coming from fragment, thanks!

Answer (score 49):

## TL;DR

Use the `android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar` and just do:

```
toolbar.inflateMenu(R.menu.my_menu)
toolbar.setOnMenuItemClickListener {
    onOptionsItemSelected(it)
}
```

## Standalone Toolbar

Most of the suggested solutions like `setHasOptionsMenu(true)` are only working when the **parent Activity has the Toolbar in its layout** and declares it via `setSupportActionBar()`. Then the Fragments can participate in the menu population of this exact *ActionBar*:

> Fragment.onCreateOptionsMenu(): Initialize the contents of the Fragment host's standard options menu.

**If you want a standalone toolbar and menu for one specific Fragment** you can to do the following:

*menu_custom_fragment.xml*

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_save"
        android:title="SAVE" />
</menu>
```

*custom_fragment.xml*

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    ...
```

*CustomFragment.kt*

```
override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    val view = inflater.inflate(layout.custom_fragment, container, false)
    val toolbar = view.findViewById<Toolbar>(R.id.toolbar)
    toolbar.inflateMenu(R.menu.menu_custom_fragment)
    toolbar.setOnMenuItemClickListener {
        onOptionsItemSelected(it)
    }
    return view
}

override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
    return when (item.itemId) {
        R.id.menu_save -> {
            // TODO: User clicked the save button
            true
        }
        else -> super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
    }
}
```

Yes, it's that easy. You don't even need to override `onCreate()` or `onCreateOptionsMenu()`.

PS: This is only working with `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` and `android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar` (also be sure to use `AppCompatActivity` and an `AppCompat` theme in your `styles.xml`).

Comment: really helped a lot to me

Comment: Is there an alternative to `onPrepareOptionsMenu` in this case?

Comment: This was my problem! Thanks!

Answer (score 27):

In the `menu.xml` you should add all the menu items. Then you can hide items that you don't want to see in the initial loading.

**menu.xml**

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_newItem"
    android:icon="@drawable/action_newItem"
    android:showAsAction="never"
    android:visible="false"
    android:title="@string/action_newItem"/>
```

Add `setHasOptionsMenu(true)` in the onCreate() method to invoke the menu items in your Fragment class.

**FragmentClass.java**

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
}
```

You don't need to override `onCreateOptionsMenu` in your Fragment class again. Menu items can be changed (Add/remove) by overriding `onPrepareOptionsMenu`method available in Fragment.

```
@Override
public void onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    menu.findItem(R.id.action_newItem).setVisible(true);
    super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);

}
```

Answer (score 21):

In my case, here is the steps.

## Step-1

```
@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Here notify the fragment that it should participate in options menu handling.
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
}
```

## Step-2

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    // First clear current all the menu items
    menu.clear();

    // Add the new menu items
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.post_stuff, menu);

    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}
```

## Step-3

```
 @Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.post_stuff:
            Log.d(TAG, "Will post the photo to server");
            return true;
        case R.id.cancel_post:
            Log.d(TAG, "Will cancel post the photo");
            return true;
        default:
            break;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: I already had menu on main activity, using `menu.clear()` cleared previous menu. Worked for me :)

Comment: i have ViewPager with Fragments, the menu.clear() was the missing part thanks!

Answer (score 21):

There is a new way of doing this since `androidx.activity:activity:1.4.0`

You are supposed to use the [MenuProvider](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/core/view/MenuProvider) API.

It is used as follows:

Instead of calling `super.setHasOptionMenu` and implementing `onCreateOptionsMenu` you are supposed to call `addMenuProvider` in `onViewCreated`.

An Example:

```java
class ExampleFragment : Fragment(R.layout.fragment_example) {

  override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    // The usage of an interface lets you inject your own implementation
    val menuHost: MenuHost = requireActivity()
  
    // Add menu items without using the Fragment Menu APIs
    // Note how we can tie the MenuProvider to the viewLifecycleOwner
    // and an optional Lifecycle.State (here, RESUMED) to indicate when
    // the menu should be visible
    menuHost.addMenuProvider(object : MenuProvider {
      override fun onCreateMenu(menu: Menu, menuInflater: MenuInflater) {
        // Add menu items here
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.example_menu, menu)
      }

      override fun onMenuItemSelected(menuItem: MenuItem): Boolean {
        // Handle the menu selection
        return true
      }
    }, viewLifecycleOwner)
  }
```

source: [Activity Changelog](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/activity#1.4.0-alpha01)

Comment: latest and modern way to add menu with fragment.. 

Comment: @Gesit      val menuHost: MenuHost = requireActivity() ? can you elaborate this ? 

MenuHost given type, but you set FragmentActivity instead

Comment: @GideonSteven MenuHost is just an interface which is implemented by FragmentActivity. It would also be possible to make menuHost FragmentActivity and call these methods directly.

Answer (score 17):

You need to use menu.clear() before inflating menus.

```
@Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        menu.clear();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    }
```

and

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    }
```

Comment: This is correct when you want different menus in different fragments and you are adding fragments instead of replacing them.

Comment: Thank you! menu.clear() help me remove the menu option of Activity.

Answer (score 8):

If you want to add your menu custom

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
}

@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_custom, menu);
}
```

Comment: what if there is a tab view and you want to inflate different menus for each fragment?

Answer (score 7):

I've had the same problem, my fragments were pages of a ViewPager. The reason it was happening is that I was using child fragment manager rather than the activity support fragment manager when instantiating FragmentPagerAdapter.

Answer (score 3):

Menu file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/play"
        android:titleCondensed="Speak"
        android:showAsAction="always"
        android:title="Speak"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_play">
    </item>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/pause"
        android:titleCondensed="Stop"
        android:title="Stop"
        android:showAsAction="always"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_pause">
    </item>
</menu>
```

Activity code:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.speak_menu_history, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {

        case R.id.play:
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "speaking....", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return false;

        case R.id.pause:
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "stopping....", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return false;

        default:
            break;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Fragment code:

```
@Override

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {

        case R.id.play:
            text = page.getText().toString();
            speakOut(text);

            // Do Activity menu item stuff here
            return true;

        case R.id.pause:
            speakOf();

            // Not implemented here
            return true;

        default:
            break;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your code is fine. Only the super was missing in the method :

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    // TODO add your menu : 
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.my_menu, menu);
    //TODO call super
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I was getting crazy because none of the answers here worked for me.

**To show the menu I had to call:** `setSupportActionBar(toolbar)`

Done!

Note: if your `toolbar` view isn't in the same activity layout you can't use the call above directly from your activity class, in this case you'll need to get that activity from your fragment class and then call the `setSupportActionBar(toolbar)`. Remembering: your activity class should extends the AppCompatActivity.

Hope that this answer help you.

Answer (score 2):

Set `setHasMenuOptions(true)` works if application has a theme with `Actionbar` such as `Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar` or Activity has it's own Toolbar, otherwise `onCreateOptionsMenu` in fragment **does not get called**.

If you want to use standalone Toolbar you either need to get activity and set your Toolbar as support action bar with

```
(requireActivity() as? MainActivity)?.setSupportActionBar(toolbar)
```

which lets your fragment onCreateOptionsMenu to be called.

Other alternative is, you can inflate your Toolbar's own menu with `toolbar.inflateMenu(R.menu.YOUR_MENU)` and item listener with

```
toolbar.setOnMenuItemClickListener {
   // do something
   true
}
```

Comment: This was why my menu wouldn't show up no matter what I did. Solution worked, thanks!!!!

Answer (score 2):

Now on 2022, Google deprecated [setHasOptionsMenu](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/Fragment#setHasOptionsMenu(boolean)) and you should use `MenuProvider` instead. In my experience, I got `NoSuchMethodException` on some android 11, 12 when I used `setHasOptionsMenu` method.

> This method is no longer needed when using a MenuProvider to provide a Menu to your activity, which replaces onCreateOptionsMenu as the recommended way to provide a consistent, optionally Lifecycle-aware, and modular way to handle menu creation and item selection.

This is how you add menu to your activity/fragment atm:

```
/**
  * Using the addMenuProvider() API directly in your Activity
  **/
class ExampleActivity : ComponentActivity() {

  override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    // Add menu items without overriding methods in the Activity
   addMenuProvider(object : MenuProvider {
      override fun onCreateMenu(menu: Menu, menuInflater: MenuInflater) {
        // Add menu items here
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.example_menu, menu)
      }

      override fun onMenuItemSelected(menuItem: MenuItem): Boolean {
        // Handle the menu selection
        return true
      }
    })
  }
}

/**
  * Using the addMenuProvider() API in a Fragment
  **/
class ExampleFragment : Fragment() {

  override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    // The usage of an interface lets you inject your own implementation
    val menuHost: MenuHost = requireActivity()
  
    // Add menu items without using the Fragment Menu APIs
    // Note how we can tie the MenuProvider to the viewLifecycleOwner
    // and an optional Lifecycle.State (here, RESUMED) to indicate when
    // the menu should be visible
    menuHost.addMenuProvider(object : MenuProvider {
      override fun onCreateMenu(menu: Menu, menuInflater: MenuInflater) {
        // Add menu items here
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.example_menu, menu)
      }

      override fun onMenuItemSelected(menuItem: MenuItem): Boolean {
        // Handle the menu selection
        return true
      }
    }, viewLifecycleOwner, Lifecycle.State.RESUMED)
  }
```

Here's [reference link](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/activity#1.4.0-alpha01).

Ah, for lazy one as me, you must add this as well:

```
dependencies {
    val activity_version = "1.5.1"

    // Java language implementation
    implementation("androidx.activity:activity:$activity_version")
    // Kotlin
    implementation("androidx.activity:activity-ktx:$activity_version")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Setting the options menu after creating the fragment view worked well for me.

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);        
}
```

Answer (score 1):

My problem was slightly different. I did everything right. But I was inheriting the wrong class for the activity hosting the fragment.

So to be clear, if you are overriding `onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater)` in the fragment, make sure your activity class which hosts this fragment inherits `android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity` (in case you would want to support below API level 11).

I was inheriting the `android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity` to support API level below 11.

Answer (score 1):

One thing I would add to this and the reason it was not working for me.

It is similar to Napster's answer.

1. **Make sure your fragment's hosting activity extends `AppCompatActivity`, not `FragmentActivity`!**

   ```
   public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

   }
   ```

   From the Google Reference [Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity.html) for FragmentActivity:

   > Note: If you want to implement an activity that includes an action bar, you should instead use the ActionBarActivity class, which is a subclass of this one, so allows you to use Fragment APIs on API level 7 and higher.
2. To update Napster's answer -- `ActionBarActivity` now being deprecated, use `AppCompatActivity` instead.
3. When using `AppCompatActivity`, also make sure you set "the activity theme to`Theme.AppCompat` or a similar theme" (Google Doc).

Note: `android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity` is a subclass of the `android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity` class (see [AppCompatActivity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/AppCompatActivity.html) ref doc).

Answer (score 1):

In your menu folder make a .menu xml file and add this xml

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_search"
    android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
    android:title="@string/action_search"
    app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
    app:showAsAction="always|collapseActionView" />
```

In your fragment class overide this method and

```
implement SearchView.OnQueryTextListener    in your fragment class



@Override
 public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {    
  super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
  setHasOptionsMenu(true);

}
```

Now just setup your menu xml file in fragment class

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);

    final MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
    final SearchView searchView = (SearchView)    
    MenuItemCompat.getActionView(item);


    MenuItemCompat.setOnActionExpandListener(item,
            new MenuItemCompat.OnActionExpandListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onMenuItemActionCollapse(MenuItem item) {
                    // Do something when collapsed

                    return true; // Return true to collapse action view
                }

                @Override
                public boolean onMenuItemActionExpand(MenuItem item) {
                    // Do something when expanded
                    return true; // Return true to expand action view
                }
            });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If all of the above does not work, you need to debug and make sure function onCreateOptionsMenu has been called (by placing debug or write log...)

If it's not run, maybe your Android theme is not supporting the action bar.
**Open AndroidManifest.xml and set the value for `android:theme` with theme support action bar**:

```
 <activity
     android:name=".MainActivity"
     android:label="@string/app_name"
     android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat">
```

Answer (score 0):

on your **onCreate** method add **setHasOptionMenu()**

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
}
```

Then **override** your **onCreateOptionsMenu**

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    menu.add("Menu item")
            .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_delete)
            .setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did to hide and unhide ALL the menu options when the fragment is loaded and destroyed, respectively. It takes the risk out of pointing to `null` for `R.id.your_menu_item` and allowed me to reuse the fragment elsewhere.

```
lateinit var optionsMenu: Menu

override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu, inflater: MenuInflater) {
    menu.iterator().forEach {
        it.isVisible = false
    }
    optionsMenu = menu
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater)
}

override fun onDestroyView() {
    optionsMenu.iterator().forEach {
        it.isVisible = true
    }
    super.onDestroyView()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In case none of the options above work for you, try this in your fragment:

```
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setHasOptionsMenu(true)
    }


    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? { 
....
        toolBar = rootView.findViewById(R.id.import_contacts_toolbar)
        toolBar?.title = "Your title"
        toolBar?.subtitle = "yor subtitile"
        contactsActivity().setSupportActionBar(toolBar)
        toolBar?.inflateMenu(R.menu.import_contacts_menu)
...
}



    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        when (item.itemId) {
            R.id.1 -> {

                return true
            }
            R.id.2 -> {

                return true
            }
        }
    
        return false
    }





    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu, inflater: MenuInflater) {
        menu.clear()
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.import_contacts_menu, menu)
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater)

        val search = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search)
        val searchView = search.actionView as SearchView
        searchView.requestFocus()

        val txtSearch = searchView.findViewById<View>(androidx.appcompat.R.id.search_src_text) as EditText
        txtSearch.hint = "Search..."
        txtSearch.setHintTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        txtSearch.setTextColor(Color.WHITE)

        try {
            val f: Field = TextView::class.java.getDeclaredField("mCursorDrawableRes")
            f.setAccessible(true)
            f.set(txtSearch, R.drawable.search_edit_text_cursor)
        } catch (ignored: Exception) {
            Log.d(TAG, "failed to expose cursor drawable $ignored")
        }

        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(object : SearchView.OnQueryTextListener {
            override fun onQueryTextSubmit(query: String): Boolean {
                return false
            }

            override fun onQueryTextChange(newText: String): Boolean {

                return true
            }
        })
        searchView.setOnCloseListener {
            
        }
    }
```

In my case I had a search menu item which was set to always visible. This is the xml for it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_search"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        app:actionViewClass="androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView"
        android:title="Search"/>

    <item android:id="@+id/1"
        android:title="1">
    </item>

    <item android:id="@+id/2"
        android:title="2">
    </item>
</menu>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to do it with a custom toolbar in a fragment. It is similar to the method by [mbo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50990935/1712184) but with the deprecated method replaced.

```
override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    this.rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_study_list, container, false) as DrawerLayout



    // Set the menu
    val toolbar = this.rootView.findViewById<Toolbar>(R.id.studylist_toolbar)

    toolbar.addMenuProvider(object : MenuProvider {

        override fun onCreateMenu(menu: Menu, menuInflater: MenuInflater) {
            // Add menu items here
            menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.studylist_menu, menu)
        }

        override fun onMenuItemSelected(menuItem: MenuItem): Boolean {
            // Handle the menu selection

            Log.d("CONJUU","Menu clicked")

            return true
        }
    }, viewLifecycleOwner, Lifecycle.State.RESUMED)
}
```