# How to Create option menu in FragmentActivity?

Tags: android, android-fragmentactivity, optionmenu

Hi Below is the code I am using to create option menu in my FragmentActivity :-

```
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    // Menu options to set and cancel the alarm.
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            // When the user clicks START ALARM, set the alarm.
            case R.id.start_action:
                alarm.setAlarm(this);
                return true;
            // When the user clicks CANCEL ALARM, cancel the alarm. 
            case R.id.cancel_action:
                alarm.cancelAlarm(this);
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Will anybody tell me why it's not working? It is not affecting app but nothing is happening when I click the option menu button from device. Please Help to resolve this.
Thanks in advance!

Below is my main.xml :-

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/start_action"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"
        android:title="@string/start_text" />
    <item android:id="@+id/cancel_action"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"
        android:title="@string/cancel_text" />
</menu>
```

Comment: Have you added SetHasOptionsMenu(true) to your fragment?

Comment: @AdityaGupta:- It is a FragmentActivity. Should I have to add SetHasOptionSMenu(true) in each fragent I am creating on that FragmentActivity?

Comment: Yes, if that fragment wants to participate in options menu handling.

Comment: I tried as you suggested but nothing happening. .

Comment: Go through this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8308695/android-options-menu-in-fragment

Answer (score 1):

Return item within Switch case like.  ITs Work For me.

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        // When the user clicks START ALARM, set the alarm.
        case R.id.start_action:
            alarm.setAlarm(this);
            return true;
        // When the user clicks CANCEL ALARM, cancel the alarm. 
        case R.id.cancel_action:
            alarm.cancelAlarm(this);
            return true;

        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Although this question is old but to close it here is what i believe OP is missing in the code

In the

> onCreateOptionsMenu

return it with the super as super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

and in the

> onOptionsItemSelected

return it with the super as super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

all the return type is boolean so you will know it worked correctly when it returns true. Its like simillar to super.onCreate(savedInstancestate).

Answer (score -1):

Change

```
return false;
```

to

```
return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
```

as

```
   @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            // When the user clicks START ALARM, set the alarm.
            case R.id.start_action:
                alarm.setAlarm(this);
                return true;
            // When the user clicks CANCEL ALARM, cancel the alarm. 
            case R.id.cancel_action:
                alarm.cancelAlarm(this);
                return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

Edit:

Also you have to add the following to your `Fragment`

```
setHasOptionsMenu(true);
```

Comment: Sorry nothing happened. Same as before, nothing is happening on option menu click.