# How to create a title bar / settings menu with FragmentActivity?

Tags: android, android-fragmentactivity, optionmenu

I created an ActionBarActivity test app, which shows the title bar and settings menu ok. I changed `extends ActionBarActivity` to `extends FragmentActivity` and the program runs, but the title bar / menu isn't displayed.

I am using swipe tabs with ViewPager in my real app, so extending ActionBarActivity isn't an option.

The question was asked similarly in [How to Create option menu in FragmentActivity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23487510/how-to-create-option-menu-in-fragmentactivity) - but the answer isn't apparent.

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.            
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

**menu_main.xml**

```
<menu
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    >
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        app:showAsAction="never" />
</menu>
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    >

    <TextView
        android:text="@string/hello_world"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Why does using swipe tabs with ViewPager prevent you from using `ActionBarActivity` (or, as of [yesterday's release of version 22.1](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2015/04/android-support-library-221.html), `AppCompatActivity`)? `ActionBarActivity`/`AppCompatActivity` extend `FragmentActivity` so you get all of the `FragmentActivity` behavior as well.

Comment: My app is laid out with two fragments, a left and right pane. I have a ViewPager on the left pane, and each tab contains more fragments. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12088983/why-it-is-not-possible-to-use-viewpager-within-a-fragment-it-actually-is

Answer (score 4):

The issue is that `FragmentActivity` doesn't have an `ActionBar`.  The purpose of `ActionBarActivity` (which is a subclass of `FragmentActivity`) is to supply the necessary functionality to display an ActionBar in your content.  If you do not wish to use `ActionBarActivity` (or the new and improved `AppCompatActivity`), use the new class `Toolbar`, which allows you to embed an ActionBar-like View directly into your layout.

Answer (score 2):

The solution is to simply use `ActionBarActivity` rather than `FragmentActivity`.

I confirmed a `ViewPager` (containing fragments) inside a fragment works fine - contrary to most info on the form.

Comment: It comes out that ActionBarActivity (though deprecated) is an innocent grandchild of FragmentActivity. Good idea! You may accept your own answer ;-)