# Android - How to access actionbar's menu items in fragment class

Tags: android

How should I access the actionbar's menu items in fragment ?
I have tried this but nothing happened

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.menu_refresh:
        Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return true;
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}
```

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Follow this steps:

- Add setHasOptionsMenu(true) method in your Fragment.
- Override onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) and
  onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) methods in your Fragment.
- Inside your onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) Activity's method,
  make sure you return false when the menu item action would be
  implemented in onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) Fragment's
  method.

Example:

**Activity**

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getSupportMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.activity_menu_item:
        // Do Activity menu item stuff here
        return true;
    case R.id.fragment_menu_item:
        // Not implemented here
        return false;
    default:
        break;
    }

    return false;
}
```

**Fragment**

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    ....
}

@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu,MenuInflater inflater) {
    // Do something that differs the Activity's menu here
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.activity_menu_item:
        // Not implemented here
        return false;
    case R.id.fragment_menu_item:
        // Do Fragment menu item stuff here
        return true;
    default:
        break;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: if i am doing like this then it show double action items on actionbar.

Comment: Copy of http://stackoverflow.com/a/18319050/3496570 . Better give credit to whom give the Answer

Comment: This is not a copy. http://stackoverflow.com/a/18319050/3496570 is shorter and more straightforward. Don't hesitate to pass a link.

Answer (score 7):

In your fragments `onCreate` method add `setHasOptionsMenu(true);`.

If your fragment is in a ViewPager then the fragment with the ViewPager also needs the above line.

Answer (score 6):

You cant access directly ActionBar menu items in a Fragment.
What you can do is put setHasOptionsMenu(true); in onCreateView function in fragment class and this calls the function onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) in the corresponding activity.

There, you can access all the menu items you have in the action bar.
You can use:

```
MenuItem item = menu.getItem(index);
```

You have one example of using this:

in fragment onCreateView class:

```
setHasOptionsMenu(true);
```

in corresponding activity class:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    MenuItem item = menu.getItem(0);
    if(condition)
        item.setVisible(true);
    else 
        item.setVisible(false);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
        return true;
    }
    // Handle action bar actions click
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
       case R.id.action_logout:
           makeLogout();
           return  true;
       default :
           return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}
```

Comment: I want to change the state of the switch in the menu, after clicking on a button in the fragment. How can I do this?

Comment: I found my answer:
We define the variable within a fragment and then set it in function onCreateOptionsMenu.
So, we can use it in the onCreateView and change its state.

Answer (score 1):

One thing I would add to this (my reputation does not allow me to comment) and reason it was not working for me.

**Make sure your fragment's hosting activity extends `AppCompatActivity` not `FragmentActivity`!**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

}
```

From the Google Reference [Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity.html) for FragmentActivity:

> Note: If you want to implement an activity that includes an action bar, you should instead use the ActionBarActivity class, which is a subclass of this one, so allows you to use Fragment APIs on API level 7 and higher.

`ActionBarActivity` now being deprecated, use `AppCompatActivity` instead. When using `AppCompatActivity`, also make sure you set "the activity theme to `Theme.AppCompat` or a similar theme" (Google Doc too).

`android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity` is a subclass of the `android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity` class (see [AppCompatActivity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/AppCompatActivity.html) ref doc).

Answer (score 0):

Menu item main.xml file :

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="dbl.contact.manager.MainActivity" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_search"
        android:actionLayout="@layout/action_bar"
        android:icon="@drawable/searchagain"
        android:orderInCategory="0"
        android:showAsAction="always"
        android:title="search"/>

</menu>
```

This is Menu item. custom action bar like edittext in the action bar You have to create a custom layout. Here custom action_bar.xml file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<EditText 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/inputSearch"
    android:layout_width="280dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:cursorVisible="true"  
    android:hint="Search"
    android:imeOptions="actionDone"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:textCursorDrawable="@android:color/white" />
```

Then in the fragment class you to override. Just Copy and paste this code.

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        // TODO Add your menu entries here
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
         getActivity().getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
         View v = (View) menu.findItem(R.id.menu_search).getActionView();
         inputSearch = (EditText)v.findViewById(R.id.inputSearch);

            inputSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    // clientAdapter.getFilter().filter(s.toString());
                }

                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                        int after) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    // ListData.this.clientAdapter.getFilter().filter(s);
                }

                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                        int count) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    adapter.getFilter().filter(s.toString());

                }

            });

    }
```