# Android onOptionsItemSelected in fragment is not triggered for android OS below 5

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have an `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` in an `AppCompatActivity`. 
I added a custom Menu in my fragment. Everything works as expected in Android 5 and 6. But if I try this on Android 4, although I can see the toolbar, when I tap the menu items nothing happens and it does not trigger `onOptionsItemSelected`

This is my fragment:

```
public class ProfileDetailFragment extends Fragment {

   @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.profile_detail_fragment, container, false);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) v.findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_profile, menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {

        switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                getActivity().onBackPressed();
                return true;
            case R.id.tick:
                save();
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(menuItem);
        }
    }

    public void save(){
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "test", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

This is my fragment layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/fragment_master"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:clickable="true">
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

And this is my menu:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item android:id="@+id/tick"
        android:title="OK"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        tools:ignore="AppCompatResource" />
</menu>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your activity is interfering between the menu and fragment.

There are two solutions:

- Inflate and handle menu within your activity and communicate with the fragment
- Specify to the fragment for handle the menu: [Android - How to access actionbar's menu items in fragment class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24526783/android-how-to-access-actionbars-menu-items-in-fragment-class)

*Reviweing your code: make sure you return false inside your onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) Activity's method

Comment: I did pretty much what everything they suggested i the other post but my android 4 still has the same issue. Returning false also didnt change anything.
I cant do the communication with activity for some other reason but I dont see why I shouldnt be able to setHasOptionMenu to true and use the menu in fragment.