# How do I Listen events from the toolbar in fragments?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, fragment, android-toolbar

Im Making an App that consist in One activity with a tablayout and a Viewpager, I have 3 tabs where each tab has a fragment. The main activity has a Toolbar with a Swich on it.

The point is that I need listen events changes from this switch in the main activity and the fragments. Actually I called onCreateOptionsMenu and onOptionItemSelected in MainActivity and works but Is possible use this methods in fragments again? o How can I listen events from UI controls in the toolbar from a fragment?

Mi Code is:

MainActivity.java

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Toolbar myToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.my_toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(myToolbar);

    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    setupViewPager(viewPager);

    tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);



    if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this,Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
        wifiManager = (WifiManager) this.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
    }else{
        if(ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(MainActivity.this,Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)){
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Debes autorizar los permisos de ubicacion",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }else{
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},LOCATION_REQUEST_CODE);
        }
    }


}

private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager){
    ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    adapter.addFragment(new OneFragment(), getString(R.string.tabRedes));
    adapter.addFragment(new TwoFragment(),getString(R.string.tabRedesGuardadas));
    adapter.addFragment(new ThreeFragment(),getString(R.string.tabMapas));
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menuactionbar,menu);
    final SwitchCompat switch1= (SwitchCompat) menu.findItem(R.id.switch_wifi).getActionView().findViewById(R.id.switchForActionBar);


    if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this,Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){

        switch1.setChecked(wifiManager.isWifiEnabled());

        if(wifiManager.isWifiEnabled()){
            switch1.setText(R.string.switchOnWifiEs);
        }else {
            switch1.setText(R.string.swtichOffWifiEs);
            //wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(true);
        }

        switch1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if (isChecked){
                    switch1.setText(R.string.switchOnWifiEs);
                    wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(true);
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,R.string.switchingOnWifiEs,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else{
                    switch1.setText(R.string.swtichOffWifiEs);
                    wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(false);
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,R.string.switchingOffWifiEs,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });

    }else{
        if(ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(MainActivity.this,Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)){
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Debes autorizar los permisos de ubicacion",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }else{
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},LOCATION_REQUEST_CODE);
        }
    }


    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){

    switch (item.getItemId()){
        case R.id.menu_settings:
            Intent nav = new Intent(MainActivity.this,configuracion_Activity.class);
            startActivity(nav);
            return true;
        case R.id.menu_acercade:
            Intent nav2 = new Intent(MainActivity.this,acercade_Activity.class);
            startActivity(nav2);
            return true;
        default:
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Estas entrando en e Default",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android - How to access actionbar's menu items in fragment class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24526783/android-how-to-access-actionbars-menu-items-in-fragment-class)

Comment: you can override onCreateOptionsMenu/onOptionsItemSelected etc at the fragment level as well. You might find this handy - If you're using android studio, you can press Ctrl+O to see functions you can override based on where you're currently looking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**In your CheckedChangeListener of Switch**

```
  switch1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                    if (isChecked){
                        switch1.setText(R.string.switchOnWifiEs);
                        wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(true);
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,R.string.switchingOnWifiEs,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();                 
                    }
                    else{
                        switch1.setText(R.string.swtichOffWifiEs);
                        wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(false);
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,R.string.switchingOffWifiEs,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
final Fragment currentFragment = getFragmentManager().findfragmentId(R.id.container);
if(currentFragment instance HomeFragment){
((HomeFragment)currentFragment).switchClicked(isChecked);
}


                }
            });
```

**In your fragment :**

```
public void switchClicked(final boolean isChecked){
...... your code.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer by myself, IDK if is the best way but works fine for me:

in my fragment:

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater){
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    final SwitchCompat switch1= (SwitchCompat) menu.findItem(R.id.switch_wifi).getActionView().findViewById(R.id.switchForActionBar);

    switch1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if(isChecked){
                fab.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            else{
                fab.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

you should check this out
[How to get Toolbar from fragment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26998455/how-to-get-toolbar-from-fragment)

this helped me a long time ago. d: