# Android: How to increase badge from view pager fragment of MainActivity?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, badge, optionmenu

I've created badge in `MainActivity`. It's working perfectly from activity. But in `MainActivity`, I've taken `ViewPager` and I need to increase badge count from fragment. Any idea how to achieve this?

```
  @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.cart_menu, menu);

    menuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_cart);
    menuItem.setIcon(buildCounterDrawable(count, R.drawable.ic_cart));

    return true;
}

  @Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.action_cart) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, CartActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("id", orderid);
        startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_REQUEST);
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

This is the method for **Badge** count increment

```
   private Drawable buildCounterDrawable(int count, int backgroundImageId) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.counter_menuitem_layout, null);
    view.setBackgroundResource(backgroundImageId);

    if (count == 0) {
        View counterTextPanel = view.findViewById(R.id.counterValuePanel);
        counterTextPanel.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    } else {
        TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.count);
        textView.setText(String.valueOf(count));
    }

    view.measure(
            View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED),
            View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
    view.layout(0, 0, view.getMeasuredWidth(), view.getMeasuredHeight());

    view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    view.setDrawingCacheQuality(View.DRAWING_CACHE_QUALITY_HIGH);
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getDrawingCache());
    view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);

    return new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bitmap);
}

public void doIncrease(int val) {
    count = val;
    invalidateOptionsMenu();
}
```

[image: Menu]
On Click of plus button, I need to increase the count. Totally unaware how to achieve this

Comment: What do you mean by "badge" and "badge count"? What does the user actually see on the screen? What will the user do and what happens in the app when the user does it? We can provide better help if you answer these questions and show us what your app is supposed to do. One way is to give mock screens in your question.

Comment: So the badge is in your activity. What you want to do is change something in that badge from a User interaction from  a fragment. Is that right...?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice **Badge** - it shows that something is there which user need to show and count shows that number of items

Comment: @AMANSINGH Can you show some mock screen shots to illustrate how badges work in your app?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice please go through the ques again, I updated the image

Comment: @AkhilSoman please refer the ques again, I updated the image. On click on plus button i need to increase the count

Comment: Which part of the screenshot is the "badge"? How will the user interact with it? Is it clickable?

Comment: on click of plus button it should be increase. This cart icon is in activity where above code is written. but this I need to use the method **doIncrease()** in this fragment image

Comment: `OptionMenu` is created in MainActivity but i need to make changes from fragment

Comment: Please check my answer

Comment: If I understand correctly, clicking on the plus button is supposed to increase the badge count. Is that correct? What screen uses the badge count? Is it displayed somewhere? Is it used in a calculation?

Comment: yes, you got correctly. i'm using sqlite for calculating the items.

Answer (score 0):

First Create a new Interface Class

```
public interface OnStepCompletedListener {
     void onStepCompleted(int position);
}
```

Now implement this interface in your Activity class.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnStepCompletedListener{
```

and implement the method(in your activity)

```
@Override
public void onStepCompleted(int position){
//
// invoke method to change the badge number here
//
}
```

Now inside your fragment. Add this code where you want to change the badge.(inside the '+' button click)

```
try{
     ((OnStepCompletedListener) getActivity()).onStepCompleted(0);
//This will invoke the implemented method in your activity class. You 
//can pass any type of value through to your activity. Just add the 
//parameter in your interface declaration.
}catch (ClassCastException e){
     e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: always getting exception

Comment: where are getting exception..?

Comment: try catch block `ClassCastException`

Comment: you have created the interface as a separate class right...? And you have implemented it in your activity class.

Comment: yes. I created interface in separate package of interface in separate class in implemented in my activity

Comment: i'm using this interface in adapter class bcoz data is in `RecyclerView` not in fragment

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132365/discussion-between-akhil-soman-and-aman-singh).

Answer (score -1):

Define count variable as static and access it from the menu layout class and thereby put the value of static count onto the textview.
I have done adding menu from the fragment and this was the code:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
}

@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    // TODO Add your menu entries here
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}
```

Comment: this code is for creating `OptionMenu` not for badge increament

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24526783/android-how-to-access-actionbars-menu-items-in-fragment-class