# Android Fragments - How to change the ActionBar on a different fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a 3 page Fragment in my app, but I need each fragment to have a different ActionBar. For one fragment I have set the current code in the `OnCreateView` method that adds in an `EditText` to the ActionBar:

```
    //mainActivityContext is the context for the Main Activity (This is a fragment file)
    ActionBar actionBar = mainActivityContext.getActionBar();
    // add the custom view to the action bar
    actionBar.setCustomView(R.layout.actionbar_view);
    search = (EditText) actionBar.getCustomView().findViewById(R.id.searchfield);
    actionBar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM
            | ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_HOME);
```

Yet this `EditText` stays persistent throughout all of the ActionBar menus. I only want it on one. I have tried everything, `menu.clear();`, `setHasOptionsMenu(true);`, `inflater.inflate(R.menu.different_file, menu);`, but nothing has worked.

Any help?

Comment: You can try keeping the same EditText but different strings.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android Options Menu in Fragment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8308695/android-options-menu-in-fragment)

Answer (score 1):

There is a very good approach to go about this situation:

on each fragment's `onActivityCreated()` method call `setHasOptionsMenu(true);`

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
}
```

now you can override `onCreateOptionsMenu()` and `onOptionsItemSelected()` inside each fragment.

And also dont forget to call `getActivity().supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();` inside `onResume()` of fragment.

I think [this sample](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html#OpenClose) by google will be very helpful.

Comment: When I use this all of the buttons on the ActionBar clear but not the EditText? Is there something wrong with the code to create the EditText?

Comment: may be because it is created after invalidation of action bar.

Comment: The EditText is being created from a separate Fragment, that hasn't had onCreateView called yet?

Answer (score 0):

Since the actions are populated by the activity's options menu you can use `Activity#invalidateOptionsMenu()`. This will dump the current menu and call your activity's `onCreateOptionsMenu/onPrepareOptionsMenu` methods again to rebuild it.

If you're using action bar tabs to change your fragment configuration there's a better way. Have each fragment manage its own portion of the menu. These fragments should call setHasOptionsMenu(true). When fragments that have options menu items are added or removed the system will automatically invalidate the options menu and call to each fragment's onCreateOptionsMenu/onPrepareOptionsMenu methods in addition to the activity's. This way each fragment can manage its own items and you don't need to worry about performing menu switching by hand.

Comment: can achieve the same with fragments. implementing this in activity with increase complexity in project.

Comment: I have tried this, but the all of the ActionBar items (There are buttons as well) go away, but the EditText persists. Should I just try a whole different code to add in an EditText?

Comment: I tried in my application. it work fine for me. But i use tabhost. he need to check with this for Fragments.

Comment: I'm using fragments with no tabs, found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18413309/how-to-implement-a-viewpager-with-different-fragments-layouts