# Using openOptionsMenu() in onOptionsItemSelected() in fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, menu, menuitem, oncreateoptionsmenu

I've got settings button at the right of my actionbar.

`main.xml` from `rsc/menu`:

```
  <item
    android:id="@+id/action_settings"
    android:icon="@drawable/settings"
    android:orderInCategory="1"     
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    android:title="Settings" />
  <item
    android:id="@+id/action_help"
    android:orderInCategory="2"     
    android:showAsAction="withText"
    android:title="Help" />
```

I want menu with other items opens after pressing this button in actionbar.
So I've added `getActivity().openOptionsMenu()` to my fragment in `onOptionsItemSelected()` function:

```
    @Override
        public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
            menu.clear();
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
            super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
        }
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected( MenuItem item) {

            switch (item.getItemId()) {

            case R.id.action_help:{
                //make help activity
            }
                return true;                       

            case R.id.action_settings:{

                getActivity().openOptionsMenu();
                }
                    return true;

            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
            }

        }
```

As I understood we can't use `openOptionsMenu()` in `onCreateOptionsMenu()`
But how to solve this issue by another way?

Comment: I need to have settings button in titlebar. And after pressing this button settings menu shows.

Comment: try `startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_SETTINGS));`

Comment: thnx for replying, but it opens device's settings, but I need app's one. In other situations `openOptionsMenu()` works good! I need the same solution

Comment: I don't know if this is your problem but in the fragment menu you have to setHasOptionsMenu in the fragment onCreate to get to the fragment menu inflater.   see:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8308695/android-options-menu-in-fragment and http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html.

Comment: I've already get it. Menu works good when I press button on phone, but I want to do it programmatically.