# How to hide option menu?

Tags: android, menu, android-actionbar, optionmenu

I am using option selected menu item, attached three item (share, login, logout) am select login item, go login activity login social sign (Facebook or google) any one, if login hide login item at same time show logout item, this same type if logout the social sign show login item menu, please help me...

[image]

Comment: Some good answers in this post: [https://stackoverflow.com/a/68490157/7348019](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68490157/7348019)

Answer (score 33):

step:1) menu.xml define all three menu item. login ,logout and share after that make logout visibility to false by default

```
android:visible="false"
```

and make remaining two items visible.its **optional** because by default all items are visible in android

Step:2)when you are in login Activity inflate that xml.and no need to make any change in activity
at these point we are showing login and share menu item only and we have already made logOff item visibility to false in the xml .

step:3) when you are in main activity(activity that you are showing after login activity) do these

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {

    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);

    MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.login_id);
            item.setVisible(false);//
    MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.logOff_id);
            item.setVisible(true);
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}
```

at these point you will get logOff and share because we have made login menu item visibility to false .

Comment: Am asking if login Facebook or google plus any one hide login item, show logout menu item

Answer (score 15):

In your `Activity` after successful login take handle of the `menuItem` in `ActionBar` and change it's visibility state

```
getMenu().findItem(R.id.login_menu_id).setVisible(false);
```

If you're using `Toolbar` then it will be like

```
toolbar.getMenu().findItem(R.id.login_menu_id).setVisible(false);
```

So `setVisible(boolean)` will change the visibility of a `menuItem`. Hope this helps

Comment: Am asking if login Facebook or google plus any one, hide login item, at same time show logout menu item

Comment: Yeah u can do with the same above code! What's the difficulties you're facing?

Comment: Hi Kevin, am using two activity main activity and login activity, to create menu item in main activity (menus : share, login, logout) we go login acitvity -> am set facebook and google plus, am if facebook login go to main activity using "registercallback method" via intent to main activity, it same to google plus, my problem for menu item not function

Answer (score 0):

and via index also we can do in both callback methods `onCreateOptionsMenu or onPrepareOptionsMenu`

```
 @Override
 public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
     if(!(boolean)PrefUtils.getFromPrefs(this,Constants.IS_LOGIN,false)) {
         menu.getItem(1/*R.id.nav_settings*/).setVisible(false);
     }
     return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
 }
```