# How to hide menu item dynamically

Tags: android

I have to hide menu item dynamically.
Below I have written menu.xml file code

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <group android:checkableBehavior="single" android:id="@+id/menu1">
            <item
                android:id="@+id/Admin"
                android:title="Admin" />
        </group>
        <group android:checkableBehavior="single" android:id="@+id/menu2">
            <item
                android:id="@+id/Worker"
                android:title="Worker" />
        </group>
    </menu>
```

I have to hide Admin menu while logging with Worker.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set visibility in Menu programmatically android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9030268/set-visibility-in-menu-programmatically-android)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to hide option menu?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32175845/how-to-hide-option-menu)

Answer (score 6):

Below changes it will help you to hide/show menu in dynamically on your program

```
private Menu menuList;

.
.
.

@Override

 public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
{

    this.menuList = menu;
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.options, menu);
    return true;
}

// ........

private void hideMenu()
{

    MenuItem item = menuList.findItem(R.id.submitmenu);
    item.setVisible(false);
}


private void showMenu()
{

    MenuItem item = menuList.findItem(R.id.submitmenu);
    item.setVisible(true);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this .

```
 @Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuItem menu1 = menu.findItem(R.id.menu1);
    menu1.setVisible(false);
    MenuItem menu2 = menu.findItem(R.id.menu2);
    menu2.setVisible(false);
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Call the method wherever you want..

```
private void hideItem()
    {

        Menu nav_Menu = navigationView.getMenu();
        nav_Menu.findItem(R.id.nav_adduser).setVisible(false);
    }
```

I hope this may help you

Answer (score 1):

**Try this**

```
MenuItem menuItemLogout = nvDrawer.getMenu().findItem(R.id.nav_logout);
menuItemLogout.setVisible(true);
```