# Create OptionMenu in Fragment

Tags: android, xamarin, optionmenu

I am working on xamarin android application.I am not able to create OptionMenu in **Fragments**. I have tried this code but not worked.

```
public override void OnCreateOptionsMenu (IMenu menu, MenuInflater inflater){
    inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.Menu,menu);
    base.OnCreateOptionsMenu (menu, inflater);
}
```

What is the solution?

Answer (score 3):

You need to add setHasOptionsMenu(true); in onCreate();

Please refer this link :

https://stackoverflow.com/a/8309255/3118054

Answer (score 1):

on your methode `public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)` in the fragment add this instruction

`HasOptionMenu=true;`

and then you have to override the method  OnCreateOptionsMenu(IMenu menu, MenuInflater inflater) in your fragment like this

```
public override void OnCreateOptionsMenu(IMenu menu, MenuInflater inflater)
    {
        inflater.Inflate(Resource.Menu.menu_search1, menu);
        base.OnCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);

        var searchItem = menu.FindItem(Resource.Id.action_search);
        searchItem.SetVisible(true);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not add Options menu in Fragments but in FragmentActivity and that FragmentActivity will act like container which will contain your fragments as well as your OptionsMenu.

Fragments basically replaces a Layout from where they are called, so you would have to use the CreateOptionsMenu from where you are calling that Fragment.

Comment: It is mentioned perfectly.If i take activity then I can add OptionMenu.But for Fragments it is not working

Comment: You tried Option menu in your MainActivity or whatever activity you are calling the Fragment from?