# Button not visible on ListView in emulator though it is visible on the Renderer

Tags: android, android-listview, floating-action-button

This is my code in list view layout xml file

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@android:id/empty"
        android:text="No schedules available"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </TextView>

    <ListView android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"
        android:layout_gravity="right|bottom"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="89dp"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:id="@+id/add_schedule"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_add_fab"
        android:background="#00ffffff"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />


    </RelativeLayout>
```

The button is visible in renderer but not in my emulator. Suggesstions would be a lot helpful
This whole setup is in a master detail flow

Comment: Before doing anything I would recommend that you check your code in a real device because the appearance in both graphic renderer and emulator can be misleading. And as a side note, are you using Android Studio?

Comment: Yes I am using android studio

Comment: I think that you are setting up the image button as a floating action button (FAB). In that case you might be better of using the official FAB widget instead of creating your own. It is done as <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton/ > It will simplify your process and minimize odd behaviour

Comment: Tested in a real device still not working

Comment: Thank you I'll try that but even my menu bar is not appearing. I've followed all the steps in this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8308695/android-options-menu-in-fragment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, your button is displayed in emulator, but you don't see it, because it might be hidden under ListView.

You would said:

> "My `ListView` is in the left bottom corner of `RelativeLayout`".

Partially you're right, but look - you set width as `match_parent`. Change this attribute to let's say `30dp` and I'm sure you would see your button.

Try as others suggest `Floating Action Button` (`FAB`). Here's a nice tutorial how to use it properly: https://guides.codepath.com/android/floating-action-buttons

If you don't like standard implementation of it, look at this page:
https://android-arsenal.com/tag/173

Hope it help

Comment: Thanks for writing... Tried changing the width and height but the list is filling the parent even then.

Comment: If you really need this button look for how to put it over the layout or use FAB

Comment: Even the fab is rendered in android studio preview but I cant see it in the emulator

Comment: did you put it into RelativeLayout? If yes, please put it under Relative Layout

Comment: Solved it, Thanks for the fab links