# Explicitly starting activity from menu item not working

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-menu

using *android 2.3.3* and Android *API 25*.

having 3 activities `activity_main` , `activity_details` and `activity_settings`.
I've used android studio auto generating for creating these activities as **blank activity with fragment**, So manifest code is generated automatically.

`activity_main` and `activity_details` have menu option `Settings` that's for opening the `activity_settings`.

clicking on `Settings` option menu for `activity_details` works and opens `activity_settings` but not working for `activity_main`

and here is my code:

**MainActivityFragment.java** and **DetailActivityFragment.java** (same)

```
`@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (item.getItemId() == R.id.action_settings) {
        startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), SettingsActivity.class));
        return true;
    }
}`
```

**menu_detail.xml**

```
`<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="com.example.poula.sunshine.DetailActivity">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="Settings"
        app:showAsAction="never" />
</menu>`
```

**menu_main.xml**

```
`<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="com.example.poula.sunshine.MainActivity" >
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="Settings"
        app:showAsAction="never" />
</menu>`
```

Comment: post code (never post images of code) , we need to see more of it

Comment: which part exactly ? I just don't want readers to get bored.

Comment: you need to post complete `activity_main.java` file , post all related java and xml files code

Comment: what happens on clicking it? do you get anything on LogCat?

Comment: at API 25 there is 2 files created when using **blank activity with fragment** `MyfileActivity` and `MyfileActivityFragment` .. which one?

Comment: I knew the problem !! I'm posting the solution in a minute

Comment: post `MyfileActivity`

Comment: when creating new `blank activity with fragment` **Android Studio** by default automatically generate `FilenameActivity.java`, `FilenameActivityFragment.java` and also other files for design.. the hierarchy that code run with when I try to override `onOptionsItemSelected` method in `FilenameActivityFragment.java` it runs the default code generated in `onOptionsItemSelected` method in `FilenameActivity.java` (just return true),, but if someone can type a more readable answer and describe it better it will be great if you got me @Pavneet_Singh

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8308695/android-options-menu-in-fragment