# how to apply click on menu item from fragment in android

Tags: java, android, xml

I am trying to access menu item so that I can apply click event but I am unable to do this because I have use given code for display and click menu item i have one activity inside there is fragment i have to access menu item in fragment and there i have apply click function on menu but i don't know why this not coming please suggest me what wrong with given code

**Menuitem.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_advance_search_query"
        android:enabled="false"
        android:title="@string/label_search"
        app:showAsAction="always" />
</menu>
```

**Activity Call**

```
override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem?): Boolean {
        when (item?.itemId) {
            R.id.action_advance_search_query -> {
//                if (mListener != null) {
//                    mListener?.onAdvanceSearchQuery()
//                }
            }
            }
        return false

    }

    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu?): Boolean {
        val inflater:MenuInflater = menuInflater
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_cs_search_advance, menu);

        return true;

    }
```

**Fragment Call:**

```
  onCreatView{
  setHasOptionsMenu(true)
           }
     override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu?, inflater: MenuInflater?) {
            inflater?.inflate(R.menu.menu_cs_search_advance, menu)
            this.menu = menu

            super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater)
        }

        override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem?): Boolean {
            when (item?.itemId) {
                R.id.action_advance_search_query -> {
                    if (mListener != null) {
                        mListener?.onAdvanceSearchQuery()
                    }
                }
            }
            return false

        }
```

Comment: Look into this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8308695/android-options-menu-in-fragment

Comment: @Abhishekkumar i alredy tried this but in Optionitemselected method not calling