# Run code in ActionBar Tab Fragment when tab is removed

Tags: android, tabs, android-actionbar

I've got Fragment ActionBar Tabs with an TabListener attached to every tab. In my main activity I got a delete tab button as follows:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle item selection
    switch (item.getItemId()
        case R.id.closeTab:
            closeTab();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

public void closeTab() {
    if(getActionBar().getTabCount() > 1) {
            Tab tab = getActionBar().getSelectedTab();
            getActionBar().removeTab(tab);
    }
}
```

What I'm trying to accomplish is to run some code in my tab-fragment before it gets removed. I could place this in the fragments `onDestroyView()` or `onDestroy()` but I only whant to run this code when I press my delete tab button.
I have checked the documentation for the `TabListener` but it seems like TabListener only listens to selectionchanges.
My TabListener:

```
public TabListener(Activity a, String t, Class<T> c) {
    activity = a;
    tag = t;
    myClass = c;
}

/* The following are each of the ActionBar.TabListener callbacks */
public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) { 
    // Check if the fragment is already initialized
    if (fragment == null) {
        // If not, instantiate and add it to the activity
        fragment = Fragment.instantiate(activity, myClass.getName());           
        ft.add(android.R.id.content, fragment, tag);

    } else {
        // If it exists, simply attach it in order to show it
        ft.attach(fragment);
    }
}

public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    if (fragment != null) {
        // Detach the fragment, because another one is being attached
        ft.detach(fragment);
    }
}

public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
}
```

**To clarify my question**: How can I run code in my Fragment before the tab is removed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okey, I figured it out after reading this post: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11443292/1168301).
In my fragment I put `setHasOptionMenu(true)`

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true); 
}
```

And then I could just add `onOptionsItemSelected` in my fragment.

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
// Handle item selection
switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.closeTab:
        closeTab();                
        return true;
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

public void closeTab() {
    ActionBar actionBar = getActivity().getActionBar();
    if(actionBar.getTabCount() > 1) {
            Tab tab = actionBar.getSelectedTab();
            actionBar.removeTab(tab);
            Log.d(TAG, "CLOSED TAB");
    }
}
```