# Adding items to ActionBar in a Fragment

Tags: c#, android, menu, android-actionbar, fragment

I'm trying to figure out how to add items to the `ActionBar` menu through a `Fragment`. My application's `MainActivity` is inheriting `ActionBarActivity` and I want to be able to change the items on the `ActionBar` based on which `Fragment` is currently showing.

```
public class LoginFragment : BaseFragment
{
    //...

    public override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        SetHasOptionsMenu(true);
        // this.Activity.MenuInflater.Inflate(Resource.Menu.something, ???);
    }
}
```

Comment: why shouldn't you inflate .xml file for this work.

Comment: Sure, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to access the objects I need to manipulate. `OnCreateOptionsMenu` for my `MainActivity` requires an argument of `IMenu`. Where does that come from?

Comment: you can create a custom function and just make a global refrence in activity and it will be initialize in onCreateMenu

Comment: you need to simply call that function from anywhere in activity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copied From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6279571/fragment-not-receiving-menu-callbacks/23091455#23091455)

```
   1. Remove or comment any onOptionsItemSelected() ,onMenuItemSelected() even onPrepareOptionMenu() and leave in Activity onCreateOptionsMenu() only:

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
    MenuInflater inflater=getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.layout.menu, menu);
    return true;
    }
```

2. In Fragment class, in onCreateView(), put:

   ```
   setHasOptionsMenu(true);
   ```
3. In Fragment class add :

   ```
   @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu,inflater);      
    }

   @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){           
            switch(item.getItemId()){
            case R.id.action_insert:
               //doing stuff
            return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
   ```

Tested and worked on Android 4.4

Comment: Ahh, I was trying to find the override for onCreateOptionsMenu. I didn't realize it returned void for Fragments.